# Writing inverse Greek letters

Tags: packages, greek

Is there any package that allows to write inverse Greek letters? Kind like nabla is inverted delta, but with all of the letters.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you have any particular application in mind?

Comment: Do you mean upside-down? Math-mode or normal text?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `graphicx`'s `\scalebox` or `\rotatebox`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}\begin{document}
\raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{-1}[-1]{$\Delta$}} $\Delta$.
\raisebox{\depth}{\rotatebox{180}{$\alpha$}} $\alpha$.
\end{document}
```

This gives you:

[image]

Comment: It gets a little tricky if the letters have descenders.

Comment: true, but this can be fixed i guess. let's wait until the OP specify what exactly they want